# Is there a env variables for slave node home in JENKINS?

Tags: jenkins

We know there's a environment variable named JENKINS_HOME so we can use it anywhere as $JENKINS_HOME.
But now when I running projects on slave nodes, I need to use the home directory of jenkins (which named "remote FS root" when defining a slave node) on slave node as a variable.  And I found $JENKINS_HOME always be the home directory of jenkins on master node even I'm running projects on slave node.

Anyone can help?  Thank you!

Comment: I just added a environment variable name SLAVE_HOME to solve this problem.
Go to the definition of slave node -> find "node properties" -> "environment variables" -> add a variable named SLAVE_HOME and set the value as the value of "remote FS root".
Then I can use this variable in Ant script.

Comment: Is this env variable available for tool installation scripts also?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but seems never answered

The variable is not directly exposed in the job's environment, but you can figure it out ...

By default (ie: you did not set a custom workspace),

`WORKSPACE=<RemoteFS>/<JOB_NAME>`
and `JOB_NAME` includes folders if you use them.

ie: `WORKSPACE=/path/to/remoteFSroot/myfolder/jobname`
and `JOB_NAME=myfolder/jobname`

You can manipulate from there.
But, there should be no need to store the data inside the remoteFS root and is even probably a bad idea, since you should be able to delete all the workspaces w/o impacting your data. Just store it in another directory (or even an NFS shared across all you slaves) and reference with a complete path.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable, it just a side-effect of the script you use to start Jenkins master. You cannot trust it to be always available.

Maybe you could explain why you think you need to know the slave home directory?

Comment: In my case:  Large amount (15GB) of read-only data shared between projects needs to be present for building.  Prefer to reference a deterministic location (and install/update as required) rather than bloating the workspaces of numerous projects.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jenkins pipeline plugin, I retrieve the remote root directory of the slave node where the job is running at with

```
run.getEnvironment(listener).get("BASE")
```