# How do I retrieve the remote FS root from declarative Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a heavyweight base project that rarely changes over time and has a lot of header files. I've set it up to be built in a custom workspace with a relative path `base`. So on a *remote* node with FS root set to `C:\Jenkins`, the resulting path on that particular node will be `C:\Jenkins\base`.
The reason for this setup is that I don't want to copy or unpack the whole base project for every dependent project to save build time. Also, I don't want to use absolute paths because I like the idea of a self-contained jenkins installation.

Now I have a second project `project` that uses `base`. I need to specify the path of `base` to the build system of `project` so that it will find the `base` headers it needs.

Is there any way to retrieve the remote FS root through the environment? I've tried using `${env.JENKINS_HOME}` but this always resolves to the home folder of the Jenkins master. My build system expects to find the path to the `base` project in the PATH_TO_BASE environment variable:

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            parallel {
                stage('Build Linux x64') {
                    agent {
                        label "Debian9_x64"
                    }
                    steps {
                        withEnv(["PATH_TO_BASE=${env.JENKINS_HOME}/base"]) {
                            sh '''mkdir -p _build
                            cd _build
                            cmake ..
                            cmake --build .'''
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Build Windows10') {
                    agent {
                        label "Windows10"
                    }
                    steps {
                        withEnv(["PATH_TO_BASE=${env.JENKINS_HOME}/base"]) {
                            bat '''if not exist _build mkdir _build
                            cd _build
                            cmake ..
                            cmake --build .'''
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I found another question essentially asking for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116687/is-there-a-env-variables-for-slave-node-home-in-jenkins

Comment: Provided a better answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116687/is-there-a-env-variables-for-slave-node-home-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually configure slave with a set of environment variables.

- Go to the slave configuration
- Set Environment varaible under "node properties" section.

Comment: I hoped there was some built-in feature I just missed. But I can perfectly live with this solution. Thank you.