# How to specify custom path for remote node on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I've a Jenkins server. It runs on D:\Jenkins.

In my jenkins file, I've the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node{
            label 'windows-node'            
            customWorkspace "${JENKINS_HOME}\\${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
        }
    }
//...
}
```

This was working fine and tries to use the D:\jenkins\feature\testbranch (by example).

I now setup a new node, and it has only one disk, C:\

The remote node has the `Remote root directory` configured as `C:/ws`. So I was expecting that my output folder would be `C:/ws/feature/testbranch`.

But it seems it tries to access the `D:\jenkins\feature\testbranch` on the remote node. How to use the node specific root folder in an Jenkins file?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116687/is-there-a-env-variables-for-slave-node-home-in-jenkins

Comment: @Mahesh Even if it was a duplicate, could you at least reference a question with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

So that variable appears to be specific to the master. You probably need a environment variable which will point to a location that is consistent across your slaves (like WKSPC_LOC), set it in your windows environment and use something like  customWorkspace "${WKSPC_LOC}\${env.BRANCH_NAME}", note that you still need to set this up in every slave. In general for CI, having different things being treated same creates problems. So a slave should be the same (consistent).  As of now I don't think there is way to have different workspace locations for master and slave. In linux you could have used sym links, but I can't think of a solution for windows, except what I mentioned before, but I still doubt it will work.